# Jspdf Issue content not showing to another page when large

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
I am using jspdf here is my code problem is when content is large it does not show content to next page i am trying it from a week doesn't find answer please help ?
```

i have also tried fromhtml function but it order content to a line doesn't support bootstrap ?
i have also tried pageSplit which stretch content and make it blur ?

```
<script>
    function gen(){
    let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');

    doc.addHTML(document.getElementById('booking_review'),function() {
        var hei=$('#booking_review').height();

        if(hei > 1498){
        alert("height");
        doc.addPage();
        doc.save('html.pdf');
        }
        else{   
        doc.save('html.pdf');
        }
    });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Do you get the alert? can you post the HTML content here and/or create a fiddle for it?

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the scene but here is what I came up with...

```
 var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");

 var imgWidth = 210; // The width of jsPDF file. If you want the content to match the page's width
 var pageHeight = 295; // 

 var frameHeight = canvas.height // eg. $('#booking_review').height();
 var frameWidth = canvas.width // $('#booking_review').width();


 var imgHeight = frameHeight * imgWidth / frameWidth
 var heightLeft = imgHeight
 var heightPosition = 0


 doc.addImage(this.src, 'JPEG', 0, heightPosition, imgWidth, imgHeight);
 heightLeft -= imgHeight

 while(heightLeft >= 0){
     heightPosition = heightLeft - pageHeight;
     doc.addPage();
     doc.addImage(this.src, 'JPEG', 0, heightPosition, imgWidth, imgHeight);
     heightLeft -= imgHeight
 }

doc.save('html.pdf')
```

This was what worked for me... Just try tweaking it to your liking :D